# DialogFragment Position in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-dialogfragment

I'm trying to locate my dialog in a specific location on screen.
Here is my dialog implementation :

```
public class DayDialog extends android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment {
public static DayDialog newInstance() {
    DayDialog f = new DayDialog();
    f.setCancelable(true);
    f.setStyle(STYLE_NO_TITLE, 0);
    return f;
}
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_calendar_day, container);
    WindowManager.LayoutParams params = getDialog().getWindow()
            .getAttributes();
    params.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT;
    params.x = 0;//b.getInt("x");
    params.y = 0;//b.getInt("y");
    getDialog().getWindow().setAttributes(params);
    return layout;
}
```

here is how my dialog shown! how can I locate it (0,0) ? it's like there is a frame or something around it!

[screenshot](http://upload7.ir/images/49616831194342914269.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is fact a frame around it, that is defined in [styles.xml](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/values/styles.xml#L54), more specific it's the [this](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/drawable-hdpi/popup_full_dark.9.png) 9-patch. The way i see it you have two options:

1. Start playing around with negative top/left margin params until you align it exactly where you want it (watch out to use dpi values).
2. Apply the `DialogFragment.STYLE_NO_FRAME` like so:

   ```
   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);       
       setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NO_FRAME, 0);
   }
   ```

Comment: thank's for your answer! I decided to use PopupWindow! it's exactly what I want! :-)